# finding the sum function of $\sum_ {n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n-2}{(n-1)!} z^{n+1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

finding the sum function of $\sum_ {n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n-2}{(n-1)!} z^{n+1}$

So far i've substituted n-1 for m which gives me the following form:

$\sum_ {m=0}^{\infty} \frac{m-1}{(m)!} z^{m+2}$.

Note that this function looks a lot like $e^x$. but we obviously see:

$e^x = 1 + \frac{z}{1!} + \frac{z^2}{2!} \cdots$

but my function looks like:

$-1 + \frac{z^2}{2!} + \frac{2z^3}{3!} + \frac{4z^4}{4!} \cdots$

I think i need to subract and sum $e^x$ with some term but i don't see how. Any hints/tips/tricks?

Kees

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n-2}{(n-1)!}z^{n+1} = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{n-1}{n!}z^{n+2} = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{z^{n+3}}{n!}-\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{z^{n+2}}{n!} = (z^3-z^2)\,e^z.$$

Comment: can you explain step 3?

Comment: @KeesTil: $$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{n}{n!}z^{n+2} = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n}{n!}z^{n+2}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(n-1)!}z^{n+2}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{z^{n+3}}{n!}.$$

Comment: @KeesTil: then $$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{z^{n+k}}{n!} = z^k\,e^x.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n-2}{(n-1)!}z^{n+1}=z^4\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n-2}{(n-1)!}z^{n-3}=z^4\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n-1)!}z^{n-2}\right)'=\cdots$$

Comment: this is pretty smart, but the sum term in the accent is not exactly the $e^x$ but $xe^x$ right?

Comment: @KeesTil, in fact, $e^z/z$. In any case, you can calculate the derivative easily.